# Prime ideals in Quotientring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Consider $k[X,Y]/(X+Y)$ where k is a field. The task is to find the prime ideals of that ring. As far as I know, these correspond to the prime Ideals of $k[X,Y]$ that contain $(X+Y)$. Since this is generated by one element, namely $(X+Y)$, these must devide $(X+Y)$. The only prime ideal that does so would be $(X+Y)$. Therefore the only prime Ideal of $k[X,Y]/(X+Y)$ is $(X+Y)$. Is this correct or are there mistakes in my argumentation? Also, do I need to care for the (0) Ideal at one point? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not the only prime ideal of $k[X,Y]$ containing $(X+Y)$.

Comment: Remember that a prime ideal in $K[X,Y]$ can have more than one generators, so there are other prime ideals that contain $(X+Y)$. You may think of $K[X,Y]/(X+Y)$ as the ring $K[X,Y]$ where you set the relation $Y = -X$ (so you basically get a ring that is isomorphic to $K[X]$).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How would I determine what other prime ideals there are in this ring? This is something that is a subtask of a bigger one, therefore I don't think this can be too hard, however I'm clearly missing something then.

Comment: Yes you are right, its not a principal ideal domain, maybe I was mixing something up here. However, how can I determine the other prime ideals? And why can I think of $-Y=X$? I've seen this idea sometimes, but never really understood it entirely. Thank you! @JoelCohen

Comment: Look at Joel's comment: can you determine the prime ideals of $k[X]$? @eu271828

Comment: In the ring $K[X,Y]/(X+Y)$, we have $X+Y = 0$, so $Y = -X$. And thus, any polynomial can be rewritten just in terms of $X$ using $P(X,Y) = P(X,-X)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't remember what the prime ideals of that ring are, I only remember that it is a principal ideal domain, I'm sorry.

Comment: Why can I just treat it like that? The 0 element of the ring would be $(X+Y)$ not $X+Y$ wouldn't it? Why can I just then treat it like a normal equation? @JoelCohen

Comment: In the ring $K[X,Y]/(X+Y)$, every multiple of $X+Y$ is $0$. In particular, $X+Y$ itself is $0$. And we have $Y = -X$ since their difference is $X+Y$, which is $0$.

Comment: @JoelCohen Thanks, that makes perfect sense. In order to now determine the prime ideals of the Quotientring above, I would like to find an isomorphism from $k[X]$ to $k[X,Y]$ in order to state that the images of prime ideals are prime in $k[X,Y]$. Did I understand you correctly? If so, I'm sorry but I don't know how to go from here.